# Uploads to get multiple Video IDs, but the they don't return all data [items]

Tags: python, youtube-api

Newbie coder here, wanting to code for research purposes. I used Jupyter, Python 3

```
playlist_id = 'UUYk4LJI0Pr6RBDWowMm-KUw'
```

and then

```
def get_video_ids (youtube, playlist_id):
    
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part='contentDetails',
                playlistId = playlist_id,
                maxResults = 50)
    response = request.execute()
    
    video_ids = []
    
    for i in range (len(response['items'])):
        video_ids.append(response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['videoId'])
        
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
    more_pages = True
    
    while more_pages:
        if next_page_token is None:
            more_pages = False
        else:
                request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                            part='contentDetails',
                            playlistId = playlist_id,
                            maxResults = 50,
                            pageToken = next_page_token)
                response = request.execute()
                
                for i in range (len(response['items'])):
                    video_ids.append(response['items'][i]['contentDetails']['videoId'])
                
                next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')
                    
    return video_ids
```

to get a long list of video ids

```
video_ids = get_video_ids (youtube, playlist_id)

def get_video_details (youtube, video_ids):
    
    all_video_stats = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.videos().list(
                part='snippet,statistics',
                id=','.join(video_ids[i:i+50]))
        response = request.execute()
    
    for video in response ['items']:
        video_stats = dict(
                        Title = video['snippet']['title'],
                        Publish_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                        View_Count = video['statistics']['viewCount']
                        #Comment_Count = video['statistics']['commentCount']
                            )
        all_video_stats.append(video_stats)
    
    return all_video_stats
```

when i tried to use `get_video_details (youtube, video_ids)`

It only shows 24 data, instead of all hundreds of videos in it.
Help?

Was expecting to get hundreds of data with the use of `len()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect for the second `for` loop of `get_video_details`, use instead:

```py
def get_video_details (youtube, video_ids):
    
    all_video_stats = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 50):
        request = youtube.videos().list(
                part='snippet,statistics',
                id=','.join(video_ids[i:i+50]))
        response = request.execute()
    
        for video in response ['items']:
            video_stats = dict(
                            Title = video['snippet']['title'],
                            Publish_date = video['snippet']['publishedAt'],
                            View_Count = video['statistics']['viewCount']
                            #Comment_Count = video['statistics']['commentCount']
                                )
            all_video_stats.append(video_stats)
    
    return all_video_stats
```